# Laravel - Create a session array and add to it every time the page is reloaded

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session, session-variables

Where and how do I instantiate a session array, how do I add to that session array, and how do I access that session array?

I know similar questions have been answered, but people are only sharing one line of code at a time without file names, so I have no idea where that code goes.

I need to create a session array in Laravel so that when I text my Twilio account with the word 'add' followed by a string it will either create the array and add the string to it or if the array is already created it will simply add the string to the already created array. I need to be able to text repeatedly with new strings to add to the array, which is why I need a session array. I will later be adding functionality to text 'list' and 'remove' to list and remove items from the array.

I am capable of getting the incoming string.

**routes.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/sms/{incomingString}', 'SMSController@toDo');
```

I am passing the string to my controller, which then gives it to my view.

**SMSController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SMSController extends Controller
{
    public function toDo(Request $request, $incomingString)
    {
        return view('sms', ['incomingString'=>$incomingString]);

    }
}
```

Next, I am taking the array and exploding it, so if the text is 'add' do the dishes' it will take $result[0] and see that it is 'add,' and then I have $result[1] as 'do the dishes.' My goal is to append $result[1] to whatever session array I create.

**sms.blade.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;

$result = explode(" ", $incomingString, 2);

if ($result[0] == 'add')
{
    //add $result[1] to session array
}

$response = new MessagingResponse();
$response->message('You have added ' . $result[1] . ' to your chore list');
```

Laravel's documentation has helped me out quite a bit thus far, but on this subject, I am having trouble finding out where I use the lines of code documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session.

Answer (score 0):

Create a session like:

```
Auth::login(YOUR_ARRAY);
```

Now load in every page: Like

```
Auth::user()->id;//
```

Comment: Which of these files do I create the session in? Do I just load it at the top of every page it is being used in? Thank you.

Comment: Session created in Login Method ,Controller, and can call in every file.